# prevent WorkoutSession to update Activity ring

Tags: watchkit, healthkit, watchos

I'm developing an apple watch application (WatchOs4). I'm interested to monitor heart rate, so I'm using a WorkoutSession to get continuous data updates. The problem is : when I start a workout session, it will automatically update the exercise ring of the Activity Rings on the watch. As it's not a sport app, I would like to prevent that.

Does anyone have a solution for that ?

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered that if you pause the workout session heart rate is still collected, but calories and exercise minutes are not.

```
session.startActivity(with: Date())
session.pause()
builder.beginCollection(withStart: Date()) { (success, error) in
    guard success else {
        // Handle this
        return
    }
}
```

It's really that easy. Months of trying to figure this out and the internet didn't have an answer.

Note that the Health App will still technically shows calories being collected, but it seems to only be about 15-20 per hour which doesn't seem to be more than usual for just wearing the watch normally.

Answer (score 1):

Please check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkoutsession
Filling the Rings section.

Set your workout in one of the following activities run, walk, cycle, stair climbing, elliptical, and rowing activities which provide customized calorie calculations. So if you didn't move, nothing will be contributed to the ring.

FYI I only tried indoor walking.

Comment: When **indoor walking** is used, the "exercise" ring is not updated, but the "move" ring and the "stand" ring are (even when the user does not really move). When **indoor orther** category is used, the "exercise" ring is updated, and the two others aren't. So it seems changing the category is not a solution

Comment: Which version of Apple Watch are you using? You should file a radar to Apple.