# How not to fill the activity rings, using workout session in WatchOS

Tags: objective-c, healthkit, watchos

My task is to get data on the pulse in realtime. For this, I save the data in HealthKit using the workout session type “other”..
The problem is that when using this and other tested types of workout sessions, such as yoga, running and so on, the activity rings are filled.
How to get rid of it? Please help me, this problem keeps me awake.

All types of workout sessions
tried to not store data to HealthKit after session complete

```
HKWorkoutConfiguration *config = [HKWorkoutConfiguration new];
config.activityType = HKWorkoutActivityTypeOther;
config.locationType = HKWorkoutSessionLocationTypeIndoor;
HKWorkoutSession *wSession = [[HKWorkoutSession alloc] initWithConfiguration:config error:&error];
[self.healthStore startWorkoutSession:wSession];

[self.healthStore endWorkoutSession:self.workoutSession];
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried by posting some code.

Comment: So your logging activity but don't want that activity to count towards daily goals?

Comment: No, im just want to get heart rate without filling activity ring. To do this, i'm starting workout session. I heard something about not storing data to healthkit after workout is complete, but im not sure (

Comment: Pause the workout session as soon as it is started. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64288974/8174191